# Linking a SharePoint list to a SharePoint document library

Tags: json

I am teaching myself JSON, but I have a simple questions I haven't found a solution for.  I am looking for a JSON to link a SharePoint list to a SharePoint library. It is in the same SharePoint site, but different subsites.

Ideally I would use the information in 'title' for the SharePoint site, to do the query in the SharePoint document library.

(Using sharepoint online 365)

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I think we need some more information about what you mean by "link a list to a library"?  Are you wanting to copy metadata from a list to a library, or have records connected together with relational data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using the below two approaches :

1. Using SPFx extension Field customizer
2. Using Column Formatting option

In the column formatting approach we can use the below json as sample :

```
    {  

    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",  

    "elmType": "div",  

    "children": [  

        {  

            "elmType": "a",  

            "style": {  

                "padding-right": "8px"  

            },  

            "txtContent": "@currentField",  

        "attributes": {  

        "target": "_blank",  

        "href": {  

                    "operator": "+",  

                    "operands": [  

                        "mailto:",  

                        "@currentField",  

                        "?subject=Wonder women here&body=Hey ",   

            "[$Title]",  

                        "\nJust checking, if you have saved the world?.\r\n---\r\n",  

                        "\r\nClick this link for more info. http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ConferencePrep/Tasks/Prep/DispForm.aspx?ID=",  

                        "[$ID]"  

                    ]  

                }  

                  

            }  

        },  

        {  

            "elmType": "a",  

            "attributes": {  

        "target":"_blank",  

                "iconName": "Mail",  

                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",  

        "href": {  

                    "operator": "+",  

                    "operands": [  

                        "mailto:",  

                        "@currentField",  

                        "?subject=Wonder women here&body=Hey ",   

            "[$Title]",  

                        "\nJust checking, if you have saved the world?\r\n---\r\n",  

                        "\r\nClick this link for more info. http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ConferencePrep/Tasks/Prep/DispForm.aspx?ID=",  

                        "[$ID]"  

                    ]  

                }  

                  

            }  

        }  

    ]  

}
```

Details explanation is here :

[SharePoint Column Formatting - Display A Single line Of Text As Hyperlink](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-column-formatting-display-single-link-of-text-as-hyperlink/)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite unsure about your requirements, but a simpe link from one List Item to another Document could be done by a lookup or maybe a calculated column??